# Your project may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method

Tags: android, kotlin

[image]I update Android studio and add baseline profile
get this error

> Your project may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).

What do i do for build project ?

Comment: Please do not post error messages in screenshots. It is just text, so please post it as text.